# Unable to invoke Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have tried a lot with multiple ways but could not invoke Spring Controller from my jsp page. Even simple string renderring is not working. So here is the background -

I am running on Tomcat 9.0 M22 with Spring 4.3.9

My test.jsp page is containing $greeting in the body part value of which i can render it Controller.

****web.xml file****

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-fil`enter code here`e-list>
</web-app>
```

**test-servlet.xml file**

```
<bean id = "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>  
<property name="prefix" value = "/jsp/"/> 
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
```

****Controller File****

```
@Controller
public class HelloMarsTeamController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello world");

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When i invoke the URL http://localhost:8080/marsapp/jsp/test.jsp, it just luanch an empty screen with title "Test". So it seems that jsp is called but the logic of controller is not invoked.

Unable to figure what is incorrect.

Thanks for your help in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]:

Move your jsp folder into **WEB-INF** because your servlet is looking for it at webContent once you have done in your `test-servlet.xml` modify next line:

```
<property name="prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
```

Your **Dispatcher** is configured at `/test` as root you only need to call `http://HOST:PORT/test`

and modify your **Controller** like this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloMarsTeamController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sayHello() {
        return ModelAndView("test", "Greetings", "Hello from Springframework Controller");
    }

}
```

then in your **View** pass it to your `jsp` view `<div>${Greetings}</div>`

Comment: Thanks but its not working. I believe since its printing the title of the JSP file , it has loaded the JSP page but it did not routed to the controller. In my URL marsapp is the root context and my jsp file is under jsp folder. So i have to use URL as http://localhost:8080/marsapp/jsp/test.jsp. If i dont then its give page not found 404 error

Comment: Post your log please, and your tree folders please.

Comment: My Tomcat long contains details as below -                                           
21-Jul-2017 13:36:57.600 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21-Jul-2017 13:36:59.067 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'marsapp'
21-Jul-2017 13:36:59.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
21-Jul-2017 13:36:59.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()

Comment: Not here, when you try to access to your controller look at your log (latest lines) and edit the post adding it once you have done add your folders tree too please

Comment: Send you a mvc tree as separate answer since i cannot add in comment.

Comment: Nope if i move my jsp to WEB-INF and access the URL http://localhost:8080/test, its giving me page not found error. Its not even loading the jsp file. I am not sure whats wrong but it seems that my spring beans are not getting initialized. Not sure why

Comment: can  you add the entire code of your test-servlet.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Ivan,

This is what is appearing in log and that too during deployment only. No other log message is appearing in server log. Below is the screen shot of my mvc tree -

[Spring MVC Tree][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiwCC.png

Answer (score 0):

everything is fine. it is working. EL is not working.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>
```

write this on top of jsp page.